# Problem implementing DateTextField feature

Tags: java, html, wicket

I need to create some kind of a button, or link, or anything that would fill the fields with date.

So far I tried implementing a `Link` that on click would fill my `DateTextField` with required date.

Here how it looks:

[image]

I've added 9 clickable links that would fill **DateTime From** and **DateTime To**.

Now the problem. Firstly I tried making it work like this:

```
logSearchForm.add(getNewLinkDateAndHours(logSearchForm, dateLast1Hour.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")),LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")), dateLast1Hour.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")),LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")),"last1Hour"));
```

This adds a link and calls a method.

```
private Link<Void> getNewLinkDateAndHours (Form<BgwElasticSearchFields> logSearchForm, String from, String to,
                                           String fromTime, String toTime, String id) {
    return new Link<Void>(id, new PropertyModel<>(searchFields, id)){
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            logSearchForm.get("dtFrom").setDefaultModel(Model.of(from));
            logSearchForm.get("dtTo").setDefaultModel(Model.of(to));
            logSearchForm.get("timeFrom").setDefaultModel(Model.of(fromTime));
            logSearchForm.get("timeTo").setDefaultModel(Model.of(toTime));
        }
    };
}
```

But with this implementation came two problems: 1) it reloaded and cleared all the fields 2) it filled the required date fields, but when I hit Search button it wouldn't parse the date, it just tried searching with empty date.

So the I tried making it like this:

```
private Link<Void> getNewLinkDate (Form<BgwElasticSearchFields> logSearchForm, LocalDate from, LocalDate to, String id) {
    return new Link<Void>(id, new PropertyModel<>(searchFields, id)){
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            Date dateFrom = Date.from(from.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
            Date dateTo = Date.from(to.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
            searchFields.setDtFrom(dateFrom);
            searchFields.setDtTo(dateTo);
        }
    };
}
```

This one worked a little bit better, it set the date correctly, search button worked fine with the inserted date, BUT it still reloaded the whole page whenever I clicked the link and didn't save any filled fields. I tried catching and saving the inserted info, but I didn't succeed.

In perfect program it would look like this: I fill *Legal Code*, set *Bic* and I click the *Yesterday* button. Page doesn't reload or reloads keeping my inserted Legal Code and Bic values, I hit Search button, everything works fine.

Comment: hi. Have you considered to use an AJAX link to load the desired fields and refresh only them?

Comment: @AndreaDelBene No, could you give some more details?